# HTML DIV should be hidden but the position not change the existing div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I want to hide 1, 3 and 2 & 4 not change their position.

```css
div{
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: blue"><p>1</p></div>
<div style="background-color: yellow"><p>2</p></div>
<div style="background-color: red"><p>3</p></div>
<div style="background-color: green"><p>4</p></div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. ? Have you tried given those divs you want to hide a common class and hide them using opacity?

Comment: Add ```visibility:hidden``` to your css to hide elements without changing the page flow.

Comment: How do you intend to hide them? Is there a button or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

visibility hidden only for hiding the element here but element position will left as blank so you can see white spaces rather than element. it is advisable to use class or id to get accurate result

```css
    div {
      width: 10%;
      float: left;
    }
.blue{
visibility:hidden;
}
.red{
visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue" style="background-color: blue">
  <p>1</p>
</div>
<div class="yellow" style="background-color: yellow">
  <p>2</p>
</div>
<div class="red" style="background-color: red">
  <p>3</p>
</div>
<div class="green" style="background-color: green">
  <p>4</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

visibility hidden will keep the space of the element but not show it:

```css
div {
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
}

div:nth-child(1),
div:nth-child(3) {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: blue">
  <p>1</p>
</div>
<div style="background-color: yellow">
  <p>2</p>
</div>
<div style="background-color: red">
  <p>3</p>
</div>
<div style="background-color: green">
  <p>4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `nth-child` can be a solution to select, just in this case, it should be (1) and (3)

Comment: @Cédric - yes thanks, have edited to hide 1 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

You could set their opacity to 0, that whay they wont be visible and they wont affect the other div's positions

```css
.box{
  display: flex;
}

.blue{
  opacity: 0;
}
.red{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">  
  <div class="blue" style="background-color: blue"><p>1</p></div>
  <div style="background-color: yellow"><p>2</p></div>
  <div class="red" style="background-color: red"><p>3</p></div>
  <div style="background-color: green"><p>4</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Lalalena Mentioned in comment, you can use `visibility:hidden`

```css
div{
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
}
.hidden{
  visibility: hidden;
}
.blue{
  background-color: blue;
}
.yellow{
  background-color: yellow; 
}
.red{
  background-color: red;    
}
.green{
  background-color: green;  
}
```

```html
<div class="blue hidden"><p>1</p></div>
<div class="yellow"><p>2</p></div>
<div class="red hidden"><p>3</p></div>
<div class="green"><p>4</p></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
div{
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: blue; visibility:hidden;"><p>1</p></div>
<div style="background-color: yellow"><p>2</p></div>
<div style="background-color: red; visibility:hidden;"><p>3</p></div>
<div style="background-color: green"><p>4</p></div>
```

;

Answer (score 0):

> [The visibility CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) shows or hides an element without changing the layout of a document.

Depending on how you want to toggle the colors here's a quick example that uses buttons to toggle the visibility of groups of elements. Inline CSS has been moved to make the HTML cleaner, and the JS easier to use. Links for MDN documentation at the bottom of the answer.

```js
// Cache the containers, and add a listener to the
// buttons container
const colors = document.querySelector('.colors');
const buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');
buttons.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

// When a child in the buttons container is
// clicked (see event delegation below)...
function handleClick(e) {
  
  // ...first check it's a button
  if (e.target.matches('button')) {
    
    // ... destructure its id from the dataset
    const { id } = e.target.dataset;
    
    // ... and use the id to toggle those elements
    // in the colors container which have a `color` class
    // and a class that matches the id
    // (using a template string to create the selector)
    colors
      .querySelectorAll(`.color.${id}`)
      .forEach(color => color.classList.toggle('hidden'));
  
  }

}
```

```css
.colors { display: flex; width: 60%; justify-content: left; align-items: center; }
.color { width: 20%; text-align: center; border: 2px solid white; }
.red { background-color: red; }
.blue { background-color: lightblue; }
.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
.green { background-color: lightgreen; }
.orange { background-color: orange; }
.pink { background-color: pink; }
.hidden { visibility: hidden; }
.buttons { margin-top: 1em; }
```

```html
<div class="colors">
  <div class="color group3 pink"><p>1</p></div>
  <div class="color group1 blue"><p>2</p></div>
  <div class="color group2 yellow"><p>3</p></div>
  <div class="color group1 red"><p>4</p></div>
  <div class="color group2 green"><p>5</p></div>
  <div class="color group3 orange"><p>6</p></div>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <button data-id="group1">Toggle group 1</button>
  <button data-id="group2">Toggle group 2</button>
  <button data-id="group3">Toggle group 3</button>
</div>
```

Additional documentation

- [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) / [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle)
- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/)
- [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)
- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) / [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)